# Rails как сделать модель?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Извините за нубскиее вопросы, но как мне сделать такую структуру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы сделали сами и что не получилось?

Comment: @Nofate создал две модели Project, Todo но когда генерировал Project у меня получается там только поле title, а с каким типом делать поле todos не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про [связи между объектами в Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

В вашем случае каждый `Todo` принадлежит какому-то `Project`. В таком случае говорят, что есть отношение *"has-many"* между `Project` и `Todo`.

Объявляем класс `Project` содержащий `Todo`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title
  has_many :todos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

И класс `Todo`, в свою очередь ссылающийся на владеющий им `Project`:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title
  belongs_to :project 
end
```

Comment: у вас ошибка в ответе. has_many :orders

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Структура такая: 
Project> title:string

Todo> project_id:integer, text:text, completed:boolean

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```